# SQL Server format function

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I add format function, to get 'S01E02' ?

The following executes S8E72.

```
select 
    title, concat('S', season, 'E', episode) as 'episode' 
from GameOfThrones
```

I've tried with

```
select FORMAT(episode, '00')
```

Answer (score 1):

You would seem to want:

```
select title, concat('S', format(season, '00'), 'E', format(episode, '00')) as episode
from GameOfThrones2;
```

Note:  Use single quotes only for string and date constants.  Do not use single quotes for column aliases.

Comment: Right, I just started exploring SQL so really appreciate your comment! Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell more about your note or just some link to read? Why it isn't recommended? Thx

Comment: Gordon is saying the same thing I am in my answer, @demo . Single quotes (`'`) are normally for use for Literal Strings, using them for other things, like aliases, can be confusing. For example `SELECT ID AS 'MyID' FROM dbo.MyTable ORDER BY 'MyID';` would **not** sort the data in the order of `MyID`, but what ever arbitrary order SQL Server felt like, as the latter `'MyID'` would be interpreted as a literal string, not the alias of the same definition.

Comment: @Larnu, oh, that's clear about `ORDER BY` :) I thought about it isn't recommending use of single quotes... at all... need to use `[ ]` instead... Ok, thx

Answer (score 1):

I would, personally, use `RIGHT` over `FORMAT`. `FORMAT` isn't a particularly performant function, and for much larger datasets could make your query really slow. AS a result you could do something like this:

```sql
SELECT 'S' + RIGHT(CONCAT('00',Season),2) + 'E' + RIGHT(CONCAT('00',Episode),2) AS Episode --Don't use single quote for aliases, it's confusing as single quotes are for literal strings
FROM dbo.YourTable                                                                         --Stick to the dialects delimit identify or ANSI's double quotes (")
```